# Solving Diophantine Equation with Only Specific Variable Values Allowed

Tags: equation-solving, diophantine-equations

I am trying to Solve an equation like this:

$$
\sum _{i=1}^{\text{iMax}} (-i+\text{iMax}+1) n(i)=546
$$

Where all the $n(i)$ are can only take on the values 2,3,6,7, or 8.

I really have no idea how to tackle this problem. The only solution I have found thus far is for $\text{iMax} = 12$ and all $n(i)=7$:

```
iMax = 12;
nArr = Array[n, iMax];
eq = Sum[(iMax - i + 1) n[i], {i, iMax}] == 546;
fI = FindInstance[{eq, nArr < 8}, nArr, PositiveIntegers, 1]
(*{{n[1] -> 7, n[2] -> 7, n[3] -> 7, n[4] -> 7, n[5] -> 7, n[6] -> 7, 
  n[7] -> 7, n[8] -> 7, n[9] -> 7, n[10] -> 7, n[11] -> 7, 
  n[12] -> 7}}*)
```

For other values of `iMax` that aren't 12, solutions are generated in the positive integers, but the `n[i]` are not all 2,3,6,7, or 8.

```
possVals={2,3,6,7,8};
iMax = 13;
nArr = Array[n, iMax];
eq = Sum[(iMax - i + 1) n[i], {i, iMax}] == 546;
fI = FindInstance[{eq, nArr < 8}, nArr, PositiveIntegers, 1]
Complement[Flatten[nArr /. fI], possVals]
(*{{n[1] -> 7, n[2] -> 6, n[3] -> 7, n[4] -> 6, n[5] -> 6, n[6] -> 6, 
  n[7] -> 6, n[8] -> 5, n[9] -> 5, n[10] -> 5, n[11] -> 5, n[12] -> 4,
   n[13] -> 4}}*)

(*{4, 5}*)
```

Asking for more solutions doesn't help, and is very slow:

```
iMax = 13;
nArr = Array[n, iMax];
eq = Sum[(iMax - i + 1) n[i], {i, iMax}] == 546;
fI = FindInstance[{eq, nArr < 8}, nArr, PositiveIntegers, 2]
Complement[Flatten[nArr /. #], possVals] & /@ fI
(*{{n[1] -> 7, n[2] -> 7, n[3] -> 6, n[4] -> 7, n[5] -> 3, n[6] -> 6, 
  n[7] -> 7, n[8] -> 4, n[9] -> 7, n[10] -> 5, n[11] -> 7, n[12] -> 5,
   n[13] -> 1}, {n[1] -> 7, n[2] -> 5, n[3] -> 6, n[4] -> 7, 
  n[5] -> 4, n[6] -> 6, n[7] -> 7, n[8] -> 7, n[9] -> 7, n[10] -> 6, 
  n[11] -> 3, n[12] -> 7, n[13] -> 2}}*)

(*{{1, 4, 5}, {4, 5}}*)
```

Is there a way to ask `FindInstance` to search for solutions that are only made up of `n[i]` values being 2,3,6,7 or 8?

Or perhaps there is a way to do this with something else like `IntegerPartitions`?

Comment: @Bill Thank for the comment. Although this is nice because it adds another solution (13 6's) I am interested in all solutions for distinct `n[i]`, not just the ones where all the `n[i]` are the same number

Comment: With each `n[i]` potentially but not necessarily, being distinct, If I haven't made any mistakes, ALWAYS a possibility. iMax==11 has zero solutions.
iMax==12 has 83285 solutions, the first is {2,8,8,8,8,8,7,8,8,8,8,8}.
iMax==13 has 4255796 solutions, the first is {2,2,6,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8}.
iMax==14 has 32118710 solutions, the first is {2,2,2,3,8,8,8,8,8,7,8,8,8,8}. That text file of solutions is a gigabyte and I don't want to grind out a 7+ gigabyte file of solutions for iMax==15. Please check all this carefully before you trust it.

Comment: @Bill Thanks for putting so much work into this. May I ask how you got those answers?

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I will write a brute force search in c++. Hopefully I can think of an elegant way to do this in mma though one day.

Comment: Because of the number of 8's in the the early solutions, this `iMax=12;ResourceFunction["SelectTuples"][{8,7,6,3,2},iMax,(Sum[(iMax-i+1)*#[[i]],{i,iMax}]==546)&,10]` QUICKLY finds the first ten solutions and you can verify each of those results in 546.

Comment: `iMax=13;ResourceFunction["SelectTuples"][{8,2,3,6,7},iMax,(Sum[(iMax-i+1)*#[[i]],{i,iMax}]==546)&,10]` and `iMax=14;ResourceFunction["SelectTuples"][{8,2,3,6,7},iMax,(Sum[(iMax-i+1)*#[[i]],{i,iMax}]==546)&,2]` You get the idea.